# ruby works for normal users but not for root

Tags: sudo, root, ruby

I have an ubuntu 18.04 machine with ruby installed.
I login with a user that is part of the www-data group and I am able to execute this:

```
ruby myprogram.rb
```

without any issue

If I try to do

```
sudo ruby myprogram.rb
```

or

```
sudo su
ruby myprogram.rb
```

Ubuntu claims that ruby is not an installed software and you need to install it. Why?

Mi goal is to run that program as root so that it can access a directory that is owned by root and with 700 permissions: it is intended to be so stricted and i am not going to change the permissions.

How can I make that ruby program run by root?

Comment: How did you install ruby?

Comment: sudo apt-install ruby-full, that's it. And I ended up with this weird installation

Comment: Where is `ruby`? `type -p ruby` Is that directory in `root`'s `$PATH`? Does `ruby` need environment variables?

Comment: @waltinator `type - p ruby` returns `/home/netbean/.rbenv/shims/ruby`. netbean is the normal user I login with. For the root $PATH how to check it?